# Read_sql_query wrongly returns NULL

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I uses this code to query my database and sometimes it returns NULL wrongly.

```
request = SELECT Max(horodatage),valeur1, module_id FROM t_donnee WHERE localisation_id=1 AND module_id=217 AND horodatage<'2020-06-01 00:00:00'

result = pd.read_sql_query(request,conn)

display(result)
```

[wrong result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAZ88.jpg)

As you can seee the following screenshot I have data for this request when executed with adminer.

[Adminer result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV31B.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.